# Where will Noah travel to next?

Tags: pattern, knowledge, sports

Noah was born in 1989.  His parents loved a particular sport.

At the following ages he traveled to the countries below with his parents to see a particular sporting event.

At the age of 9, he traveled to the Netherlands
At the age of 13, he traveled to Malaysia
At the age of 17, he traveled to Germany
At the age of 21, he traveled to India
At the age of 25, he traveled to the Netherlands

**Question :**
What is his next age in the series?  Where he will travel to?
And what is the particular sport?
And what is the particular sporting event?

Comment: This seems more like a trivia question than a puzzle...

Comment: Wikipedia, to the rescue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He will travel

> at the age of 29 to India.

That is because the sport event is

> the [Hockey World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey_World_Cup).

Comment: This is too easy with wikipedia, you just have to look at pages like this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_in_Malaysia